# iPhone App - Trouble Getting Cells To Display Array Data

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a simple table view which I have built using an example from a book but it doesn't work..

It is supposed to take the values from an array and display them in the cells within a table view. I have connected the table views dataSource and delegate to the file's owner and have the following code in my controller class:

**Simple_TableViewController.h**

```
@interface Simple_TableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *listData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listData;
@end
```

**Simple_TableViewController.m**

```
#import "Simple_TableViewController.h"

@implementation Simple_TableViewController
@synthesize listData;

-(void)viewdidLoad{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sleepy", @"Sneezy", @"Bashful", @"Happy", @"Doc", @"Grumpy", @"Dopey", @"Thorin",@"Dorin", @"Nori", @"Ori", @"Balin", @"Dwalin", @"Fili", @"Kili", @"Oin", @"Gloin", @"Bifur", @"Bofur", @"Bombur", nil];
    self.listData = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.listData = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [listData release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.listData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row]; 
    return cell;
}
@end
```

The project succeeds when compiling, but no text displays in the table cells...

**UPDATE**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Simple_TableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tv;
    NSArray *listData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* listData;
**@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView* tv;**
@end

#import "Simple_TableViewController.h"

@implementation Simple_TableViewController
@synthesize listData, tv;

-(void)viewdidLoad{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sleepy", @"Sneezy", @"Bashful", @"Happy", @"Doc", @"Grumpy", @"Dopey", @"Thorin",@"Dorin", @"Nori", @"Ori", @"Balin", @"Dwalin", @"Fili", @"Kili", @"Oin", @"Gloin", @"Bifur", @"Bofur", @"Bombur", nil];
    self.listData = array;
    **[tv reloadData];**
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.listData = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [listData release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.listData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    NSString *msg = @"message";
    NSLog(@"%@", msg);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row]; 
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: how many sections you are returning?

Comment: This tableview has only one section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the numberOfSections datasource method.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return 1;
}
```

Also after changing the data in your array, you'll want to reload the table.

```
[yourTableViewHere reloadData];
```

Comment: Where is your table view being created? The code you've posted here is just a UIViewController, not a UITableViewController. In order for this to work you need to create the tableview yourself and set the delegate and dataSource to this VC. Here's a guide explaining how to create a populate a table view. http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/

Comment: I created a TableView using interface builder and set the delgate and dataSource to the file's owner. This is the only controller class in my classes folder.. UIViewController should be fine as UITableViewController is just one of it's subclasses. I used the .xib file which had the same name as my project name

Comment: Are you ever calling reloadData on your tableView?

Comment: no, all it should do is load the data from the array...the dataSource methods don't seem to get called..I have set the dataSource and the delegate to the file's owner in my .xib file which is of type UITableView and my main.xib points to my controller class, so im not entirley sure what;s going wrong...

Comment: 1) Is your view controller actually being created anywhere? Throw a log in viewDidLoad. 2) You're setting the array in viewDidLoad, which will be called after the tableView is created. Therefore you need to call reloadData on the tableView otherwise it's not going to actually call any of the datasource or delegate methods.

Comment: sorry where and how should I call reloadData?

Comment: If your tableView is being created in Interface Builder then you're going to need to create an IBOutlet. What view controller is your tableView appearing in? If it's in Simple_TableViewController then create an IBOutlet there and call [nameOfYourTableView reloadData] in viewDidLoad after setting the array.

Comment: Ok so I added an outlet within the header and synthesized it in the .m. In interface builder I connected the tableview to the IBOutlet and called the method in ViewDidLoad but it still doesnt work

Comment: Is this viewController being created anywhere? Put an NSLog in viewDidLoad. If it doesn't return anything then you need to change the viewController in IB to be this class.

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment,you made tableview from xib file but where is IBOutlet correspond to tableview.  You have to make an IBOutlet UITableView *tableview and connect it with your tableview in xib file

Comment: urm I thought all you had to do was specify the delegate and dataSource

Comment: Please check if your tableview delegates are called or not by using breakpoints.

Comment: You have to call reloadData after making an outlet for your tableView